# Using "IN" when not equal in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I use "IN" when they are not equal in column.

```
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT student_id 
     FROM students 
     WHERE student_id  IN (
             SELECT student_id,
                    CASE 
                       WHEN (
                          //condition           
                       )
                       THEN 'Yes'
                       ELSE 'No'
                    END AS refusal
             FROM refusal_field
 )
) AS a USING(student_id)
```

It says: subquery has too many columns

I really need the "refusal" column for me to LEFT JOIN. How to do this?

Comment: Wow... has not a single one of the answers to any of your fifteen questions addressed your issue satisfactorily? You should [accept correct answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: haha. poor me. It's just that there so many queries.

Comment: Is this postgresql or mysql? :s

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this. This should have the result you want:

```
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT student_id,
CASE 
WHEN (
//condition         
)
THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No' 
END AS refused
FROM students 
INNER JOIN refusal_field ON refusal_field.student_id = students.student_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the subquery has 2 columns : student_id and refusal, it should only have student_id,
i believe what you want is :

```
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
      student_id,
      CASE 
         WHEN (
          //condition         
         ) THEN 'Yes'  ELSE 'No' END AS refusal
   FROM students WHERE student_id  IN (
      SELECT student_id
      FROM refusal_field
   )
) AS a USING(student_id)
```